# Frequency of non-increasing and non-decreasing subsequences

Tags: arrays, algorithm, matlab, sequences

Having a sequence of numbers of length `L`, I need to count how many non-decreasing and non-increasing sub-sequences of exact length are there. For example, if I have a sequence of length 15

### 2, 4, 11, 13, 3, 5, 5, 6, 3, 3, 2, 4, 2, 14, 15

I see that non-increasing sub-sequences are

### 13, 3

### 6, 3, 3 , 2

### 4, 2

and non-decreasing sub-sequences are

### 2, 4, 11, 13

### 3, 5, 5, 6

### 2, 4

### 2, 14, 15

So here I have

- 2 non-increasing sub-sequences of length 2
- 1 non-increasing    sub-sequence of length 4
- 2 non-decreasing sub-sequences of length 2
- 1    non-decreasing sub-sequences of length 3
- 2 non-decreasing    sub-sequence of length 4

Since the maximum length of a non-decreasing (or non-increasing) sub-sequence can be 15 in this case, I thought about representing frequencies through vectors **x** for non-increasing and **y** for non-decreasing sub-sequences:

```
x = (0,2,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0)

y = (0,1,1,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0)
```

Expanding this to general case of sequence of length **L**, I wanted to go through the sequence and, using loops, count frequencies of subsequences of the exact lengths. How would I do that? I would create zero-vectors of length L and I would add 1 to the *l*-th element of zero matrix every time I meet a sub-sequence of length *l*.

Since my sequence will be of length of few thousands, I wouldn't ask Matlab to write them, but I would ask it to write me particular frequency.

Is this a good approach?
Is there some function in Matlab that is doing this?

Comment: As you consider [3 3] as non-decreasing, you should also consider [5 5] as non-increasing. Otherwise it gets tough. `x` would be `x = (0,3,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0)` then, as in both answers.

Comment: I made a mistake. Thanks for pointing it out. 3,3 goes together with 6,3,3,2 and 5,5 goes together with 3,5,5,6. In fact, I can't classify 3,3 nor 5,5 as non-decreasing or non-increasing sequence because they are constant. I'll make a correction in the question. I will try this code and I will tell you if it works. Thank you!

Comment: Well, than you should call it "increasing" and "decreasing" and not "non-decreasing" and "non-increasing"

Comment: Actually no. Non-decreasing means that it's increasing but can include constant subsequences. Increasing is strictly increasing.

Comment: you seem not to know what you want :D

Comment: I do know :) Let a, b and c be three arbitrary numbers such that a<b<c. a,b,c is a strictly increasing sequence. c,b,a is strictly decreasing sequence. a,a,b,c is non-decreasing (it does not decrease but it has repetition of a). c,b,b,a is non-increasing (it does not increase but it has a repetition of b). Increasing sequences are non-decreasing too and decreasing sequences are non-increasing too. I am looking for such sequences. Is it ok now?

Comment: Yes I got that, that's how I understood your question. But you stated that *I can't classify 3,3 nor 5,5 as non-decreasing or non-increasing sequence because they are constant.* - and I don't agree on that. Well anyway, if you need this cases excluded, I will see how I can edit my question, but I don't have the time right now.

Comment: I meant I can't classify them like that separately from other elements. I can say that 3,3,4 is non-decreasing and that 5,5,3 is non-increasing but I can't say that 3,3 is non-increasing or non-decreasing. I need one more element different from them so I can know in which group to put them. Thank you a lot. It's not really urgent so you can try to help me when you have time in the following days. Thanks a lot. Have a nice time!

Comment: have a look at my edit, should work now!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about that lovely one-line solution?

```
%// vector
A = [2, 4, 11, 13, 3, 5, 5, 6, 3, 3, 2, 4, 2, 14, 15]
%// number of digits in output
nout = 15;

seqFreq = @(vec,x) histc(accumarray(cumsum(~(-x*sign([x*1; diff(vec(:))]) + 1 )), ...
                   vec(:),[],@(x) numel(x)*~all(x == x(1)) ),1:nout).' %'

%// non-increasing sequences -> input +1
x = seqFreq(A,+1)
%// non-decreasing sequences -> input -1
y = seqFreq(A,-1)
```

---

```
x = 0 2 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 

y = 0 1 1 2 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

---

## Explanation

```
%// example for non-increasing
q = +1;
%// detect sequences: value = -1
seq = sign([q*1; diff(A(:))]);
%// find subs for accumarray
subs = cumsum(~(-q*seq + 1));
%// count number of elements and check if elements are equal, if not, set count to zero
counts = accumarray(subs,A(:),[],@(p) numel(p)*~all(p == p(1)) );
%// count number of sequences
x = histc(counts,1:nout);
```

Answer (score 1):

For non-decreasing sequences:

```
x = [2, 4, 11,13,3,5,5,6,3,3,2,4,2,14,15]; %// data
y = [inf x -inf]; %// terminate data properly
starts = find(diff(y(1:end-1))<0 & diff(y(2:end))>=0);
ends = find(diff(y(1:end-1))>=0 & diff(y(2:end))<0);
result = histc(ends-starts+1, 1:numel(x));
```

For non-increasing sequences, just change inequalities and sign of `inf`s:

```
y = [-inf x inf]; %// terminate data properly
starts = find(diff(y(1:end-1))>0 & diff(y(2:end))<=0);
ends = find(diff(y(1:end-1))<=0 & diff(y(2:end))>0);
result = histc(ends-starts+1, 1:numel(x));
```